# Cannot find method symbol

Tags: java

I don't know if I can explain this and post the proper code to make it clear, but I will try.
I have five classes.  They are being used to check the validity of an ISBN number.  I am getting the error "cannot find symbol - method getISBN(). I have a gui object which I have instantiated.  The error comes from the Handler, here:

```
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
       if (e.getSource()==gui.validateButton)
       {
          try
          {
            gui.ISBNText.getISBN();/////////////error//////////
            gui.status.setText("ISBN " + ISBNText.bookNum + " is valid");
          }
          catch(ISBNException er)
          {
            gui.status.setText(er.getMessage());    
          }
       }
      else System.exit(0);
```

I wont post any code from the gui, you get the idea: theres a gui, it has a textfield called ISBNText, and in the ISBNText class, there is a method to retrieve my text, called getISBN, code:

```
    public ISBNText() 
{
    super(20);
}  
//retrieve the ISBN num from textfield
public String getISBN() throws ISBNException
{           
    bookNum = getText();    
    validateISBN(bookNum);
    return bookNum;      
}
```

I hope this is enough, but not too much, to go on. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the reference type of the gui? If you have SomeClass gui, what is the 'SomeClass'?

Comment: I'm using bluej, and sorry, but what do you mean what is the reference type of the gui?

Comment: I don't want to sound condescending, but why do you need 5 classes to validate an ISBN?

Comment: Because it's a homework assignment. And that didn't sound condescending, actually.  It has been strictly dictated the structure we need to adhere to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the GUI class, it's difficult to say. But I would suspect that your `ISBNText` field is declared as is :

```
JTextField ISBNText = new ISBNText();
```

If that's the case, then getISBN() can't be found because the variable's declared type is JTextField, and not ISBNText. You need to change it to

```
ISBNText ISBNText = new ISBNText();
```

Note that public variables should almost never be used, and that variables in Java should always start with a lower-case letter. You should thus call it `isbnText` rather than `ISBNText`.

Comment: You are just asking for trouble when you name your variables the same thing as your types, regardless of capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

> heres a gui, it has a textfield called
>   ISBNText, and in the ISBNText class,
>   there is a method to retrieve my text,
>   called getISBN

Well, if gui.ISBNText is a text field and not an instance of ISBNText class, then it won't be able to find your method.

Your code needs to be something like this:

```
class Gui {
    final ISBNText isbnText = new ISBNText();
}

class Main {
    void someMethod(){
        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.isbnText.getISBN();
    }
}
```